# What is the purpose of sum voltage monitor?

Tags: control-surfaces

I was looking at the design diagram of actuators. 
Every channel of the actuator is connected to a voltage differential transducer. The transducer outputs are fed to a sum voltage monitor. I could not understand its purpose.

How can summed voltage exist if there is a single sensor? Or am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps reference that diagram?

Comment: Added figure reference

Comment: Where did you get that fragment of a drawing from, and what do "REU", "PCU", etc. mean? Note the LVDT is not connected directly to the SVM on your diagram, we have no idea what processing is going on in between. My guess is an error signal (meaning the difference between the desired and measured position) is being produced somewhere in that path for controlling the surfaces.

Comment: By the way the SVM may be subtracting the LVDT's reported position (solid line from the side of the LVDT) from a commanded position (dashed line coming, I guess, from the cockpit) so it may be monitoring the error there. I have done some control theory, but not familiar with avionics and the standards and jargon used here.

Comment: Please add some references like the aircraft type, type of control surfaces we're talking about (I suppose we're talking about spoilers here, given the presence of an "Engage logic" block), etc.

Comment: Its Bombardier c series. Reu is similar to ACE. It commands the pcu.

Comment: Are you sure that SVM means Sum Voltage Monitor?

Comment: Yes.I think I found the answer. LVDT has two voltage outputs. Those two voltages are added and compared against predefined thresholds.

Comment: "*In an exemplary embodiment, a sum of secondary voltages V1 and V2 from a transducer is obtained by adding the secondary voltages together, i.e.; V1+V2. This sum of secondary voltages theoretically should be constant for all LVDT/RVDT positions, since the total length of the secondary transformer is constant.*" (patent: [Detection of faults in linear and rotary voltage transducers](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7138794))

Answer (score 1):

It compares the commanded position with the actual position, it is the standard feedback loop.

Comment: Thanks for digging up an answer for this old question! Would you please include some references (links if possible) to support and improve your answer.

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question.